# ScrollView not working in React Native when dynamically putting components based on array data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array of objects. I am placing the content dynamically using .map . My array has 6 items

The below code is not working as expected ( Can't scroll screen and only 3 array items are shown on screen )

```
const items =  data.map(function(orderItem, index) { 
        return <OrdersCard 
            key = {index}
            id = {index}
            name = {orderItem.ProductName}
            volume = {orderItem.ProductVolume}
            amount = {orderItem.ProductAmount}
            details = {orderItem.productDetails}
            onSelectQuantity = {getQuantity} /> }) 

    return (
            <View style = {{flex : 1}}>
                <ScrollView >
                    {items} 
                </ScrollView>    
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        style = {styles.cartButton}
                        onPress={() => ()}> 
                        <View>
                            <Text>Add to Cart</Text>
                        </View>  
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
    );
};
```

The code is working as expected when instead of one items , two items jsx are present . Only once is the item getting loaded even if two times items is called.

```
const items =  data.map(function(orderItem, index) { 
        return <OrdersCard 
            key = {index}
            id = {index}
            name = {orderItem.ProductName}
            volume = {orderItem.ProductVolume}
            amount = {orderItem.ProductAmount}
            details = {orderItem.productDetails}
            onSelectQuantity = {getQuantity} /> }) 

    return (
            <View style = {{flex : 1}}>
                <ScrollView >
                    {items}
                    {items}
                </ScrollView>    
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        style = {styles.cartButton}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart' , {
                        name : name,
                        price : price,
                        cartData : orderData
                    })}> 
                        <View> 
                            <Text>Add to Cart</Text>
                        </View> 
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
    );
};
```

Is it a bug or Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have 3 items and you want to display them twice. So you expect to see 6 orders, right ?

You have a bug here.

```
<ScrollView>
    <OrdersCard key=0/>
    <OrdersCard key=1/>
    <OrdersCard key=2/>
    <OrdersCard key=0/>
    <OrdersCard key=1/>
    <OrdersCard key=2/>
 </ScrollView>
```

You have duplicate keys. This is way only 3 list items will be displayed.

Comment: No. I have 6 items. In first case, only 3 items are shown without screen getting scrolled. In second case, I can see all 6 items with scrolling working. But since I have 2 items, ideally there should be 12 items. My issue is why is scrolling not working when I have one {items} tag but it is working when I have 2 {items} tag